# select only rowwith highest id value if there are identical column values

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I select all from a table, and if there are identical values of column `name` then only select the row that has the greatest `id` value so If there was a table like this:

```
  id name   age country
 ---+------+---+------- 
   1  bob    24  UK
   2  john   48  USA
   3  janet  72  USSR
   4  bob    96  Ukraine
```

it would only select the 'bob' with the highest id so the result would return:

```
  id name   age country
 ---+------+---+------- 
   2  john   48  USA
   3  janet  72  USSR
   4  bob    96  Ukraine
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to get greatest age

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a subquery to calculate the maximum ID for every name, and then return all rows that matches the IDs returned by the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM People
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM People GROUP BY Name)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30d88/2).

Comment: +1 You don't actually need the name, `WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM People GROUP BY Name)` would work just fine

Comment: @Andomar oh.. yes... since it's an id, it's already unique... i'll update my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this query

```
select * from table_name where ID in(select MAX(ID) from table_name  group by name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `not exists` subquery that filters out rows with with the same name and a greater id:

```
select  *
from    People p1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    People p2
        where   p1.Name = p2.Name
                and p2.Id > p1.Id
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way :

```
Select Table_1.* from table_1 inner join (
Select Max(ID) as ID from Table_1 Group by ID) x On Table.Id on x.ID
```