# How to update only the highest id of the same Name in c#.net database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have this Table Data for my FullSummary Database:
[image]

I want to update ONLY the "Name, Price, and Total" for the HIGHEST Id of a selected Name.

If I select "random" the "random" with Id 52 should be the only one that will have the updated data.

I tried:

```
con.Open();                       
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE FullSummary SET Name='" + addRiceTextBox.Text + "', Price='" + addPriceTextBox.Text + "', Total='" + newTotalEdit.Text + "' WHERE(Id, Name) IN(SELECT MAX(Id), Name FROM FullSummary GROUP BY Name)";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

But it gave me this error:

[image]

I found the code here: [select only rowwith highest id value if there are identical column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386021/select-only-rowwith-highest-id-value-if-there-are-identical-column-values)

And this one: [How can I select the row with the highest ID in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881424/how-can-i-select-the-row-with-the-highest-id-in-mysql) only selects an item and not update it.

Comment: You aren't even filtering the subquery to only return results with the selected name. It would be something like `WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM FullSummary WHERE Name = 'random')`, or similar (I think, off the top of my head). Obviously substitute the hard-coded name for a parameter. P.S. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and also unexpected syntax errors. Please urgently learn how to use SQL parameters to protect your code and data.

Comment: @Hacki How about using a subquery with `top 1` and `order by Id desc`?

Comment: Yikes, this looks crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues. Also, Sql Server != MySql. MySql is using a non-standard syntax there.

Comment: @ADyson your code works, but how can I make this more secure?

Comment: By learning how to use parameters properly, as I mentioned already. Any ado.net tutorial would show you. The answer below also gets you started on that.

Comment: Can I have your reference @JoelCoehoorn I really want to learn more about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support tuple comparison.  So this

```
 WHERE(Id, Name) IN (SELECT MAX(Id), Name FROM FullSummary ...)
```

Won't work.  So you should use a scalar subquery like this (with parameters):

```
UPDATE FullSummary f
SET Price=@price, Total=@total 
WHERE Id = (select max(ID) from FullSummary where name = @name)
```

Comment: I just figured out that I need to add this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textbox.Text); I already have this at my INSERT query but not at my UPDATE query. Thank you for this!

Comment: I also removed the f in "UPDATE FullSummary f"